# how to fetch product data from BluePrint ERP to WooCommerce?

Tags: integration, woocommerce, erp, blueprint

i am working on my e-store project using WooCommerce. I need to fetch product images, categories, product info, inventory into etc from an ERP called BluePrint.

any idea how may i do that?